# External hard drive corruption odd behavior

Tags: macos, ubuntu, external-hard-drive

I have a 750GB External HD, formatted exFat.

I accidentally disconnected it from my Mac OS X Yosemite without safely "ejecting" it first.

It would no longer mount on my Mac. I tried "Verify Disk" with Disk Utility, but it does not work. It tells me to "Repair Disk". I try that, it does not work.

Then I plugged it into a Windows XP machine. Nothing. It wants me to reformat.

I then plugged it into my Ubuntu machine. It works!!! Plug it back into Mac. It works!!!

WTF is going on here? This happened twice already. What is Ubuntu doing that repairs the drive?

I would like to know so in the future I can just do that without having to turn on my Ubuntu machine.

Thanks!

Comment: If I were to guess.  Ubuntu did indeed fix the filesystem corruption.    In the future don't repeat your mistake or use a better filesystem less prone to these types of problems.